# PyQt5 QDateEdit() undo

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyqt5

In a hotel booking system, I have a couple of QDateEdit fields mapped to a database record in my form. After the user updates any of these fields, the program makes a check to ensure that the room is available.  If the room is not available, I would like to restore the QDateEdit to its original value and let the user know with a QMessageBox.

QLineEdit has an undo method which works as I intend.

Furthermore, if I try to reset the QDateEdit by pulling the information from the model, it triggers the dateChanged signal again.  This isn't a huge problem as I know the original value is valid but seems wasteful to me.

How can I undo a change to a QDateEdit without generating the dateChanged signal?

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class Guest_form(QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.date_good = True

        self.date_edit = QDateEdit()
        self.line_edit = QLineEdit()
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.date_edit)
        layout.addWidget(self.line_edit)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.date_edit.setFocus()

        self.date_edit.dateChanged.connect(self.check_date)
        self.line_edit.editingFinished.connect(self.check_date)

    def check_date(self):
        self.line_edit.setText(self.date_edit.date().toString())
        self.date_good = False
        #self.date_edit.undo()  #How?
        self.date_edit.setDate(QDate.currentDate())
        self.line_edit.undo()
        print('here')

if __name__=="__main__":
    app=QApplication(sys.argv)
    myapp = Guest_form()
    myapp.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Maybe `QObject::blockSignals()` function called with `true` before date edit change and with `false` after could help?

Comment: The code example make no sense at all. Why are the line-edit and date-edit *both* connected to a slot which updates each of them simultaneously? Please try to provide a more realistic representation of your real code.

Comment: ekhumoro, I was trying to provide an example which showed I could undo on a QLineEdit and not on a QDateEdit.  I am sorry that this was unclear for you.  If you comment out the five lines referencing  line_edit it would purely reference the QDateEdit issue.  In the real world program, there is an arrival date and departure date.  The validation of the dates and whether there are rooms available happens in the same slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Qt's Undo/Redo Framework. You can find a good introduction [here.](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1187104)

Comment: I am unclear as to how this applies if I merely want to undo a date selection in a QDateEdit field.  As there is only user input rather than a command/method, I don't know how to restore the state of the QDateEdit to the point before the dateChange signal was fired?

Comment: First, add  self.undoStack = QUndoStack(self) to the diolog's __init() method, then attach self.undoStack.undo() and self.undoStack.redo() methods to proper signals.